# Odd function closure behavior in generator

Tags: python, function, closures, generator

I encountered a python behavior which I am not understanding.

**Here is a simple demo code:**

```
l = []
def ext_and_return_l(ext):
    l.append(ext)
    return l

extensions = [1, 2, 3, 4]
gen = map(ext_and_return_l, extensions)
```

Now say I want to see the terms of my generator, I have options.

**looping first, gives me what I expect:**

```
for i in gen:
    print(i)

 [1]
 [1, 2]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**using list instead, after running the demo code again:**

```
list(gen)

[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I believe this is related to function closure binding late, but I do not understand the exact mechanism in that case and would appreciate some insight here.

Comment: It's not a closure, really, just that `l` is a global variable and so each call to `ext_and_return_l` is modifying the same list.

Comment: If you need what you expect as an iterator, use `list.copy`, for instance: ```def yield_list_copy(gen):  
    """
    >>> assert list(yield_list_copy(mk_gen())) == [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]"""
    for i in gen:
        yield i.copy()```

Answer (score 1):

There is one global list `l`, and each call to `ext_and_return_l` is modifying that same list. The fact that you are using `map` to lazily apply `ext_and_return_l` to `extensions` doesn't matter.

All your loop does is print values of `l` at different times (`i` simply being re-bound to the same list over and over, not *different* lists). To see this more clearly, add a line to the loop:

```
for i in gen:
    print(id(i))  # This will print the same value on each iteration.
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, of course...I was looking for my answer in the wrong place!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @chepner's comment: when you use the `for` loop

```
for i in gen:
    print(i)
```

You are printing each iteration *immediately* after appending. When you use `list`, it's the same as:

```
results = []
for i in gen:
    results.append(i)
print(results)
```

This is because the returned list is, as @chepner mentioned, a single, global instance. To understand this further, try the following and see what you get:

```
l = []
results = []
results.append(l)
print(results)
l.append(1)
results.append(l)
print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

The **reason** for the behavior you're observing has already been stated by @chepner and @cmac: You're generating a *single* reference to the *same thing*.

In case you're looking for a solution to a problem though... I wild guess tells me you were going for a generator that both **acts** (accumulates data) *and* **yields** (the different stages of the accumulator).

Perhaps this is exactly what your contexts needs, but if I were you, I'd consider if there's a less acrobatic way of getting to your goal.

In case you need it though, you can get to what you want from your code by adding `.copy()` to the output:

```py
l = []
def ext_and_return_l(ext):
    l.append(ext)
    return l.copy()  # or tuple(l) if you want to "freeze" the output sequence.

assert list(map(ext_and_return_tuple, extensions)) == [(1,), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```